# data-ng-model values are not being updated while Using Bootstrap Time Picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

The values i choose from Time picker is not updating,but when i removed time picker and using normal textbox  updating works  what is wrong with time picker or my code ?

```
<div  data-ng-repeat="mondayBhr in businessHour.mon" class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-1 label-group" for="mondayStoreOpentimingsedit">Open</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
                    <input  id="mondayStoreOpentimingsedit" name="mondayStoreOpentimingsedit" ng-model="mondayBhr.store[0].open"  style="max-height:25px" class="col-md-2"  />
                    <script>
                        $('#mondayStoreOpentimingsedit').timepicker({
                            showMinutes:true,
                            showMeridian:false,
                            pick12HourFormat: true
                        }).next().on(ace.click_event, function(){
                            $(this).prev().focus();
                        });
                        </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks a lot for the Help in Advance !!

Comment: did you checked my answer?

Comment: This makes sense !!  but i need to generate time pickers for all the days dynamic is that possible  by a directive ? ... iam new for angular .. yet didn't used directives

Comment: yeah..you could initialize different timepicker for each element in htm.see my update you need to only add `time-picker` attribute inside you element tag

Comment: yes i see that !! I need to try it . I can let you know my doubt on this post Via Comment ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use directive while using jquery plugin to interact AngularJS

**Markup**

```
<input  id="mondayStoreOpentimingsedit" time-picker name="mondayStoreOpentimingsedit" 
ng-model="mondayBhr.store[0].open" style="max-height:25px" class="col-md-2"  />
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('timePicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        reuqire: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            element.timepicker({
                showMinutes: true,
                showMeridian: false,
                pick12HourFormat: true,
                change: function(time) {
                    //need to run digest cycle for applying bindings
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(time);
                    });

                }
            }).next().on(ace.click_event, function() {
                $(this).prev().focus();
            });
        }
    }
});
```